# reload a page with list menu option javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i'm searching the best way to reload a page withe list menu.

I know how to reload a page with simple code or by the meta but from a list menu it not easy.

Example :

List :
none
5 seconds
10 seconds
30 seconds
1 minutes
2 minutes
5 minutes

When an option is selected the page will be automatically reload from the option selected.

Do someone have an idea how to make a simple code ?

@mplungjan my code :

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function refresh()
{
document.location.reload();
 }
setTimeout(refresh,theForm.submit();
</SCRIPT> 




<FORM NAME="reloadForm" >
<SELECT NAME="sec" OnChange="refresh()">
<OPTION VALUE="0" SELECTED>None
<OPTION VALUE="5" >Every 5 secondes
<OPTION VALUE="10" >Every 10 secondes
<OPTION VALUE="30" >Every 30 secondes
<OPTION VALUE="60" >Every  minutes
<OPTION VALUE="90" >Every  minutes and half
<OPTION VALUE="120" >Every  2 minutes
<OPTION VALUE="180" >Every  3 minutes
<OPTION VALUE="300" >Every  5 minutes
</SELECT>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see why your question is voted down and likely closed. HINT: Post effort and code

Comment: Make a list with values > action click to get values > use function setInterval with callback to reload page.

Comment: 1. use onchange of a select 2. set a cookie or use localStorage so the page knows the setTimeout value your wanted

Comment: in addition to @mplungjan you might want to save the selection in the LocalStorage so after refresh you can get the value again (otherwise all state will be gone)

Comment: thanks @RafaelGadottiBachovas this is a good idea

Comment: @mplungjan my code :

Comment: @JoelHarkes that was what I meant

Comment: If you want to reload a part of the page, look into Ajax

Answer (score 0):

define the time variable as a value of option you have then use setTimeOut function to reload the page according to that variable , here the page reload after 6 seconds , this is the idea.

```
var time = 6000
setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, time);
```

Comment: with method i will risk to loose all my data in my page isn't it ?

Comment: try to read about (window.onbeforeunload , localStorage.setItem and localStorage.getItem) they will help you not to lose any of your data. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp